# Reading selection from HTML Widget in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny

I am developing a shiny App in which I am using radialNetworkR package. Though the package is great and suits my needs, the only thing is that I am unable to read the selections in R.

Below is an reproducible example of creating the chart. On running the code you would see a chart appear, on clicking on any node in the chart the selected value will show up in the selection box, and when you will select any value from the selection box, the selected value will become the center node and the chart will be rendered again.

I need to read the selected value (either when selected on the chart or in the selection box) and print it or store it an a variable. This HTML widget is javascript based, and with my lack of knowledge of javascript, I am unable to read the selected value. I am looking at the community to help me & guide me in the right direction.

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/radialNetworkR")

library(radialNetworkR)

radialNetwork(
 jsonlite::fromJSON( 
  paste0(
    readLines(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1093025/raw/a05a94858375bd0ae023f6950a2b13fac5127637/flare.json"
    )
    ,collapse = "\n"
  ),
  simplifyDataFrame=FALSE
 )
)
```

Link of the GitHub Page : [Source](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/radialNetworkR)

**Shiny Reproducible Example**

```
library(shiny)
library(radialNetworkR)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
library(data.tree)

ui<-fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Demo App "),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Radial Chart", uiOutput("demo1"))
      ))
  )))

server<-function(input, output, session) {

  Flare <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4063550/raw/a05a94858375bd0ae023f6950a2b13fac5127637/flare.json")
  Flare <- rjson::fromJSON(Flare)  

  output$demo1<-renderUI({column(10, radialNetworkR::radialNetwork(List = Flare,height = 700,width = 700))})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: is the question `shiny` related? I dont see it in your example or shiny integration functions (render, output functions)?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Sir, Yes it relates to Shiny, I have added the Shiny Reproducible example above. Thanks for pointing it out and apologies for missing that in the original post.

Comment: This current `radialNetworkR` might not be able to output any value until its code incorporates this `Tip 7a` from this https://deanattali.com/blog/htmlwidgets-tips/

Comment: @amrrs Thanks for your response. I have tried using that method, but I am not able to get it work, as I am clueless around where to put code in the javascript file.
Here is the link of the javascript file : https://github.com/timelyportfolio/radialNetworkR/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/radialNetwork.js